# Unknown background style at PHPStorm html code?

Tags: html, phpstorm

I'm new to `PHPStorm`. This is awesome software for PHP Developers. I have a small problem on PHPStorm HTML intelligent coding. When I type html code , the html code shows with `background gray color`. I don't like the background gray color.

So, I want to remove this background color. is it possible or not ?

Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable the `Tag name` **background** option in `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`, `HTML`:

[image: Tag background]

Answer (score 4):

I disabled the background in `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `Language Defaults` | `Markup Tag`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to theme my copy of PhPStorm following this websites help link http://phpstorm-themes.com/

(on Mac)
Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> PHP

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows how to edit:

[Edit Appearance](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/editor-appearance.html)

You can also have themes:

[Phpstorm Themes](http://phpstorm-themes.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Same isue, but i dint find it at the given solution.

But i DID find it here:

Preferences / Editor / Colors & Fonts / General / Injected language fragment

Disable the background there

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I encountered a similar issue, which I managed to resolve by toggling my Windows 11 appearance settings from 'Dark' mode to 'Light' mode and then back again. You can accomplish this by searching for 'dark' in the taskbar and selecting 'Turn on dark mode systemwide,' or by navigating to Personalization -> Colors -> Choose your mode.

It appears there may be a bug in PHPStorm that occasionally occurs when switching between Light and Dark modes in Windows.